# Integration of playwright test to zephyr scale

Tags: playwright

How to connect my playwright test to zephyr scale on premise network?

When we execute our playwright test locally or via jenkin, status should be updated in in respective cycle in zephyr.

Answer (score 0):

please refer and follow to this repo:

https://github.com/cenfun/monocart-reporter-examples/tree/main/integrations/zephyr-scale

Comment: Please do not make the value of the answer rely (almost) entirely on a link. Link for reference, but take the information provided by it and make it into an answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing the same integration between Playwright and Zephyr, I'm actually using this library:

https://github.com/elaichenkov/playwright-zephyr

I'm using the `Zephyr Cloud` approach, so far so good:

[image]

---

You only need to add this library:

```
npm i -D playwright-zephyr
```

And then include this reporter in your config:

```
reporter: [['playwright-zephyr/lib/src/cloud', { 
   host: 'https://yourcompany.atlassian.net', <- your company jira url
   authorizationToken: "token", <- your jira token
   projectKey: 'XZY', <- your jira project id
   testCycle: {
     name: `Playwright - ${new Date().toISOString()}`,
   },
 }]]
```

and finally, only add the id of your zephyr test case in your playwright files, using `[]`:

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('[T456] My Test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('/someURL');
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/My Title/);

  // More steps here...
});
```

Note: Despide my test case is ASBS-T456 I only use T456, because ASBS is the name of my jira project.